# image called from firebase shows up in emulator but not showing up in phone

Tags: android, imageview, firebase-storage

My app has a nav header which displays the photo of user as well as a activity that shows one
the output is shown properly on my laptop Emulator but does not show up when I run the app on a device no errors (checked to send a toast in case the info fetched is null did not trigger)

I also tried resizing the image to fit the image view using glide, the image is being saved in firebase storage and is given a URI which is saved in user's tree which is then accessed and called this all works on emulator but does not in a hand held device and I tried the other ways of running on Mobile Data in case its a router issue and different devices kindly help `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

code for the photo showing activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_id);
    pfp=findViewById(R.id.picture);
    fnameofstd=findViewById(R.id.idname);
    numofstd=findViewById(R.id.idcon);
    classofstd=findViewById(R.id.idclass);
    lnameofstd=findViewById(R.id.idLname);

    user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    userID=user.getUid();

    //takes val from database and feeds to places
    reference.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            RegisterUser reguser=snapshot.getValue(RegisterUser.class);

            if (reguser!=null)
            {
                String FNAME= reguser.fname;
                String LNAME= reguser.lname;
                String NUMBER= reguser.phnumner;
                String SUBJECT= reguser.stream;

                fnameofstd.setText("First Name:- "+FNAME);
                lnameofstd.setText("Last Name:- "+LNAME);
                numofstd.setText("Mobile Number:- "+NUMBER);
                classofstd.setText("Stream:- "+SUBJECT);
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(reguser.getpfp()).centerCrop().into(pfp);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(IDActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```